# pyinstaller: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a simple software (with `pyinstaller`) that activates the computer camera, but I am stuck with the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`. But when I run the same code using command prompt it runs perfectly as I would want.

```py
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
    
def openCamera():
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        _, frame = video.read()
        cv2.imshow("Camera display", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            break
    video.release()
    cv2.destroyWindow("Camera display")
    
main_window = tk.Tk()#.title("My PC Camera")
activate_camera = tk.Button(text="Activate camera",command=openCamera).pack()
close = tk.Button(text="Close",command=main_window.quit).pack()
main_window.mainloop()
```

I used the following command to create an executable, which ran successfully.

```py
$ pyinstaller --onefile test_camera.py
```

But, when I try to run the executable file generated it prints the following message to the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_camera.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
[8876] Failed to execute script test_camera
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy22v.png)

I think I have opencv-python well installed according to the code below

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.3.0'
>>>
```

screenshot

[image]

What could I be missing?

Comment: Your code works fine, and, when I ran the steps mentioned in your question, the program worked fine for me. Since `pyinstaller` compiled everything properly, this may be an issue where the wrong package is installed. Make sure you installed `opencv-python` (`pip install opencv-python`).

Comment: Hello Jacob Lee, opencv-python is installed but still the issue has persisted! Could there be any other suggestion please? `>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.3.0'
>>>`

Answer (score 3):

I hate to be that guy, but you've installed cv2 correct?

IIRC there's a couple different "opencvs" you can download, I believe the correct one is:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

My second thought is that you could be in a virtual environment that doesn't have OpenCV2. Considering tkinter is a part of the standard library, the only non-standard library here is OpenCV2.

Comment: my opencv-python is installed as you can see the code when I try to check it using the CMD. `>>> import cv2   
>>> cv2.__version__   
'4.3.0'   
>>>`

Comment: You are right. I was confusing environments.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! I needed to upgrade my `pyinstaller` just.
I run this code

```
pip install --upgrade pyinstaller
```

And now I get what I wanted though the size of the software is not it!

Answer (score 1):

pyinstaller 4.7 and pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2021.4 do **not** support opencv.

pyinstaller **4.5.1** and pyinstaller-hooks-contrib **2021.3** should be used.

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
pip install pyinstaller==4.5.1

pip uninstall pyinstaller-hooks-contrib
pip install -U pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2021.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I found I was confusing the environments in which I was running.