# No module named 'cv2' when it is compiled .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyinstaller

I've seen a lot of similar questions about it but none of them have been able to help me.
When I run my app as "script.py" there are no problems.
But when I compile it with pyinstaller and run it as exe, I get the exception "no module named 'cv2'.".
The module is included in the virtual enviroment and in the requirements.txt.
I have using Python 3.7.3 and opencv-python 4.5.5.62.
What can I do to solve the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: I think this entry would help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67494128/pyinstaller-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cv2

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem upgrading pyinstaller via "pip install --upgrade pyinstaller". Best Regards.

Comment: *in case* you've upvoted your own question a few times... that only draws attention you might not want.