# pyinstaller: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' (conda install opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, conda, pyinstaller, modulenotfounderror

*Note: This is very similar to this question: [pyinstaller: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67494128/pyinstaller-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cv2)*

I have an application that works fine via my IDE/ command line, but when I transform this to a .exe (via pyinstaller) everything works fine until the .exe tries to run the line `import cv2` resulting in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`.

The difference I have is that I am restricted by my companies internal processes and *must* install opencv (version 4.0.1) via `conda install opencv`; thus the accepted answer to above question (reinstall via `pip install opencv-python`) will not work.

Does anyone know of any way I can fix this error by altering my .spec file, adding a hook-*.py file, altering locations of .pyd file or anything else? Thank you!

**Environment:**

- python 3.8.10
- pyinstaller 3.6
- opencv 4.0.1
- In `C:\Anaconda\envs\{env_name}\lib\site-packages` I have a cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd file
- In `C:\Anaconda\envs\{env_name}\library\include` I have a opencv2 folder containing .hpp files and folders with further .hpp files within.